# How to smoothen a line chart plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, linechart

I want to smoothen my line chart plot and have the following code:

```
ggplot7 <- ggplot(rye) +  geom_line(aes(x=date,y=ARIS_TOP), group=1, color='blue', alpha=0.5) +
                          geom_line(aes(x=date,y=SWI_001), group=2, color='darkturquoise',  alpha=0.5) +
                          scale_y_continuous(limits = c(7, 27, by = 2 )) + 
                          scale_x_date(labels = date_format('%b'), date_breaks = '2 month') +
                          ylab('Soil Moisture (%)')+xlab('Date') +
                          labs(title=('Absolute Soil Moisture')) + 
                          stat_smooth() +
                          geom_hline(yintercept= c(9, 23), size =0.75, color='firebrick', linetype= 'dashed')

ggplot7 + theme_bw(base_family='Playfair', base_size = 15, base_rect_size = 1)
```

Online I found a few approaches, but it seems like I am not managing to find the right code for it.
This is the error message I get:

```
`geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'
Fehler: stat_smooth requires the following missing aesthetics: x and y
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Comment: Can you add the exact `geom_smooth()` call you're using to the example code? Also, the error informs you that you likely need `aes(x=date,y=ARIS_TOP)` or `aes(x=date,y=SWI_001)` in your `geom_smooth()` call.

Comment: @teunbrand I used this code:
`geom_smooth(method = 'gam', formula = y~x, span = 1.5, )`
The message I receive is the following: 
`mapping: yintercept = ~yintercept 
geom_hline: na.rm = FALSE
stat_identity: na.rm = FALSE
position_identity `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, use `aes(x=date,y=ARIS_TOP)` or `aes(x=date,y=SWI_001)` in your `stat_smooth()` call:

```
stat_smooth(aes(x=date,y=ARIS_TOP)) +
```

or

```
stat_smooth(aes(x=date,y=SWI_001)) +
```

or both commands in a row.